# How to retrieve Firebase data using firebaseServer?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, next.js

I created an app with Firebase authentication using [Next.js' starter](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-firebase-authentication) and setup the Firebase authentication and database. I can run the app just fine (log in and add messages).

Then I noticed it wasn't SSR'ing the Firebase data:

```
export default class Index extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps({ req, query }) {
    const user = req && req.session ? req.session.decodedToken : null;
    // don't fetch anything from firebase if the user is not found
    // const snap = user && await req.firebaseServer.database().ref('messages').once('value')
    // const messages = snap && snap.val()
    const messages = null;
    return { user, messages };
  }
```

I uncommented the code to see if I could SSR everything:

```
export default class Index extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps({ req, query }) {
    const user = req && req.session ? req.session.decodedToken : null;
    // don't fetch anything from firebase if the user is not found
    const snap =
      user &&
      (await req.firebaseServer
        .database()
        .ref("messages")
        .once("value"));
    const messages = snap && snap.val();
    // const messages = null;
    return { user, messages };
  }
```

The `user` and `snap` have values but `snap.val()` is null.

How can I retrieve the messages via firebaseServer?

If it's any help, [here's the whole file](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-firebase-authentication/pages/index.js).

Answer (score 0):

firebaseServer.database() === Realtime Database

The documents where being added to Cloud Firestore, not Realtime Database.

This pulls the documents from Cloud Firestore:

```
  static async getInitialProps({ req, query }) {
    const user = req && req.session ? req.session.decodedToken : null;
    const snap =
      user &&
      (await req.firebaseServer
        .firestore()
        .collection("messages")
        .get());

    const messages = snap && snap.docs.map(d => d.data());
    return { user, messages };
  }
```